# Wagtail routable page view with ajax content loading on click

Tags: ajax, django, wagtail

I have an app where i display contributor page with content like stories, videos and articles.
Stories, videos and articles are different page models.

template engine: Jinja 
framework: Django
CMS: wagtail

**I am able to load ajax content in to the tab successfully by creating separate view and corresponding url in urls.py with below ajax settings.**
*But if i try to use Wagtails routable page feature i get 404.*

Ajax settings excerpt:

```
settings = jQuery.extend(true, {}, {
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: vUrl,
                    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
                        console.log(`URL ${settings.url}`)
                        $tab.html('<br>');
                        $paneHeader.removeClass(css).addClass(css);
                        $el.trigger('tabsX:beforeSend', [jqXHR, settings]);
                    },
                    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            // $tab.html(data); //Use Json data instead of html

                            $tab.html(data.html);
                            $pane.tab('show');
                            $paneHeader.removeClass(css);
                        }, 300);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, status, message) {
                        $paneHeader.removeClass(css);
                    },
                }


@route(r'^/contributors/(?P<slug>[-\w]*)/articles')
def show_articles_contributed(self, request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        print("Inside AJAX")
        articles = Contributor.get_articles_by_authors(self.id)
        html = render_to_string("organisms/latest_articles.html", {"objects": articles})
        return JsonResponse({"html": html}, safe=True)
    else:
        return super(ContributorPage, self).serve(request)
```

URL printed from console.log
URL /contributors/test-author/articles

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```
class ContributorPage(RoutablePageMixin, PhoenixPage):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default="")
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default="")
nickname = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, default="")
```

PhoenixPage is nothing but base page with metadata which actually uses base Wagtail Page class.

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

If question is not clear i can provide more info.

Thanks

---

**I found a problem.** 
Posting a description for future visitors of this thread.

*Ajax code was not an issue here but Wagtail route implementation was.*

@route(r'^/contributors/(?P[-\w]*)/articles')   <--This route is not correct for ContributorPage

ContributorPage gives URL like /contributor/author_name,
While author_name being ContributorPage slug
I just want to append /articles to it, to get route like /contributor/author_name/articles

so correct route for ContributorPage is 
@route(/articles)

So now my main ContributorPage is live at /contributor/author_name
and 
Ajax tabs are queried using route urls like,
/contributor/author_name/articles
/contributor/author_name/videos
/contributor/author_name/stories
with corresponding route like, 
@route(/articles)
@route(/videos)
@route(/stories)

Comment: Please try reducing your code to the minimum necessary to show the problem. If the real issue is "URL X is returning a 404 when I don't expect it", then the AJAX handling code is not relevant.

Comment: Updated the main question with solution to my question posted above.

Thanks @gasman for taking a quick look.